# Can a circular list always be simulated by a proper list (ended by nil) in combination with a loop?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

I have the intuition that a circular list can be simulated by a proper list (with an end marker) in combination with a loop through the whole list over and over.  My feeling is that circular lists are cleaner since the control logic (loop) is built into the structure.  On the other hand, taking the control logic apart from the structure seems a separation of concern, which may be favored in some situation.  What I am not quite sure is in what situation is each useful.  Also I am not quite sure whether the simulation is always possible.  If not, could you please give a counter-example?

Comment: Yes.  Why is this unclear?  Why don't you list what you percieve to be the pros and cons?  (Without that, people will think you haven't done your homework, and your likely to get more "close" responses)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "normal lists with a loop"?

Comment: What is a "normal" list with a loop? Or what do you mean by simulation? A list is a list. I think the definitions are simple. There is no simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s always possible.

Pros:

- You have a circular list. This presumably is a pro, otherwise you wouldn’t be doing it.

Cons:

- For some reason you’ve wasted time implementing a wrapper around a normal list, instead of just writing a circular list in the first place.

FWIW, I came to the conclusion ages ago that all lists should be circular.  This allows you to use a single pointer, to the (notional) *last* element in the list, but you can easily insert at both the head and tail of the list in O(1) time.  Furthermore, making the list circular reduces the number of special cases in list manipulation code (there is *always* a valid node at the next pointer).

Comment: I don't see any real difference. You either, compare to a `null` pointer, special `Null` element, or you check if the next element is the `head`, to detect the end. It's an implementation detail, and I personally fail to see any advantage one over another. Also you cannot insert element at the end in O(1) if the list is singly linked, unless you store one additional pointer per list, even if it is circular.

Comment: @luk32 You absolutely *can* insert an element at the end in O(1) if it’s singly linked and circular; you just need to remember that your pointer to the list points at the tail, not the head.  The benefit of circularity is particularly high for doubly-linked lists, because it simplifies the link maintenance code.

Comment: Well, ok, this is kind of cheating. If your pointer points to the tail, then how you define order in your list? You are either redefining, (or reinterpreting) list or you make retrieving your 1st element take `O(n)` time. And still I fail to see how circularity simplifies the maintenance code. You always have special case. Could you be more specific? I gave 3 options I see, all are boundary special case for detecting the end of list, is there anything else. More generic?

Comment: @luk32 No, the first element is available at `tail->next` (which is O(1)); I should probably have said “last element”, since there is some confusion sometimes over the word “tail”.  As for doubly linked lists, the big win is when you insert or remove an element; if the `next` or `prev` pointers might be `NULL`, you have to check them before indirecting through them to fix `next->prev`/`prev->next`, whereas if the list is circular, you don’t.

Comment: Oh, I get everything now. I failed to see that `head` is  `tail->next`, so you can get both, tail and head in `O(1)`. Simplified insert/remove also makes sense. And you don't lose anything, when you want to implement "open-ended" list, because of what I said, there is always special case to detect the end. So actually doing the opposite of what OP asks about makes big sense. Well thanks for making me a bit smarter and derusting my old mind. I also think it was worth to take your time on it because you laid out nicely all the mechanics to back up all the statements in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @alastair: Your idea of making all lists circular is neat. But after some consideration, I find it would probably hinder sharing. Let `l1` be a list of four nodes. It is internally represented as a singly-linked circular list, so `l1` actually points at node 4. Now I want to define some common operations on singly-linked list. `head` is simple. But `rest` depends: If I do not want to maintain the entirety of `l1`, I can simply set the `next` pointer; however, if I do, I have to make a whole copy of all nodes except node 1.  This is unacceptable because `rest` is a frequent operation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simulate it. But you should need two pointers to control your list.
One pointer to access the current element and one pointer to hold the first element.
You have to make some logic to detect when your "current element pointer" is outside the boundaries of the list and move it to the first element.